# I want to return the length of the longest mirror sub section in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

We'll say that a "mirror" section in an array is a group of contiguous elements such that somewhere in the array, the same group appears in reverse order. For example, the largest mirror section in [1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 3, 2, 1] is length 3 (the [1, 2, 3] part). Return the size of the largest mirror section found in the given array.

```
maxMirror([1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 3, 2, 1]) → 3
maxMirror([1, 2, 1, 4]) → 3
maxMirror([7, 1, 2, 9, 7, 2, 1]) → 2
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please share what you've tried first and where you need help.

Comment: I guess you will need math function like "auto correlation" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const test1 = [1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 3, 2, 1];
const test2 = [1, 2, 1, 4];
const test3 = [7, 1, 2, 9, 7, 2, 1];
const test4 = [21, 22, 9, 8, 7, 6, 23, 24, 6, 7, 8, 9, 25, 7, 8, 9];
const test5 = [1,2,3,2,1];

function maxMirror(arr){
  
  //set output variable
  let max = 1; 
  
  //test each number
  //for each number, i represents index
  arr.forEach((num, i) => {
      //set default count
      let count = 0; 
      //see how many times current num can go up
      //and match the selected end number as it goes down
      //j represents current end starting at array end
      //k iterates up from current num; h iterates down from current end
      //stop loop when current num and current end are the same element
      for(let j = arr.length - 1, k = i, h = j; j > i; k++, h-- ){
        //if values match
        if(arr[k] === arr[h] && k < arr.length && h > -1){
           //keep increasing count
           count ++ 
        //otherwise
        } else {
          //check if count beats max before updating max
          if(count > max) max = count;
          //reset count for next current num/current end cycle
          count = 0;
          //cycle backwards by 1 to get new current end
          j --;
          //k resets to i (-1 to offset loop ++); 
          k = i - 1;  
          //h resets to j (+1 to offset loop --)
          h = j + 1;        
        }      
      }  
  });

  return max; 
}

console.log(maxMirror(test1));
console.log(maxMirror(test2));
console.log(maxMirror(test3));
console.log(maxMirror(test4));
console.log(maxMirror(test5));
```

Comment: maxMirror([21, 22, 9, 8, 7, 6, 23, 24, 6, 7, 8, 9, 25, 7, 8, 9]) should return 4 not 5

Comment: @kelvin it does; see added test

Comment: maxMirror([1, 2, 3, 2, 1]) should return 5

Comment: @kelvin see update; just fixed